# Arrow those variables!

Tags: code-golf, string, sorting

### Challenge

Robin likes having his variables declaration in the shape of an arrow. Here's how he does it:

- Input any number of strings
- Order them by ascending length
- Output them ordered by the middle to roughly form a negative arrowhead, like this (whichever order golfs the best):

  ```
  5  or  4
  3      2
  1      1
  2      3
  4      5
  ```

### Test Cases

Input:

```
bow
arrows
sheriffOfNottingham
kingRichard
maidMarian
princeJohn
sherwoodForest
```

Output:

```
sheriffOfNottingham
kingRichard
maidMarian
bow
arrows
princeJohn
sherwoodForest
```

Input:

```
a
bb
cc
```

Output (both are valid):

```
bb
a
cc

cc
a
bb
```

Input:

```
one
four
seven
fifteen
```

Possible output (the only other valid output is its vertical mirror):

```
seven
one
four
fifteen
```

### Notes

- The strings are in camelCase and have no numbers or special characters, only lowercase and uppercase letters.
- The input can be anything you like: comma-separated as one string, array, ... Any I/O format is allowed.
- Between strings with the same length, any order is accepted.

Comment: I feel like there was a very similar challenge before...but welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @Giuseppe Yeah that's what I thought after posting, there's no way it hasn't been done before. Would you be ok with me deleting it now that you've answered it?

Comment: well I've been searching for a dupe but I'm not very good at the search...we do have a [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) for posting challenges which can often catch things like that. I'm perfectly OK with you deleting it if you're worried about it being a dupe.

Comment: @Giuseppe Well it's too late, with 2 answers SE won't let me delete it. I had hoped for a better start in PPCG...

Comment: It's OK, we all start from the beginning :-)

Comment: Could you add a test case with an even number of strings?

Comment: Are we guaranteed that all strings will be unique?

Comment: @Shaggy No, that's not a necessity

Comment: May we return a list of strings?

Comment: Will strings have at least one character each?

Comment: @Adám, "*Any I/O format is allowed.*"

Answer (score 15):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

```python
lambda l:l.sort(key=len)or l[1::2][::-1]+l[::2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU6xjsIwDN35CisLoJaTYIzUGxlOujvp1pAhbZNLRBqjJFLF1xcb6PLs5/ee7du9ekynxXWXJZqpHw1EGT8K5rq72nsXbdpjhqiOUp60kvJw1E1UTJZqSy3QgVKieJuDc7/uB2sN6d@bSbTiSt1fGLzJI7HJhPHb5GASkR5nQpMzzoWaWw5psF/oWeNlM@J4xkwXhG5BCcOZnmAYXoNGtCCaN66lEVpvHP3Lr0FIz1rkBoAP1CdtYXv43NKIfTEkyz63Y2nPztXL0hpcHg)

Comment: You'll need to rearrange some stuff, but you can use `[::-2]` directly to save 5 bytes.

Comment: @Sherlock9 I tried that, but then I had to check for the length, as lists with even / uneven lengths have to be handled differently.

Comment: Also works for Python 3. Would removing "lambda l:" and "or" and make it on 2 lines to save 11 bytes still be acceptable as "Any I/O format is allowed" ?

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>63</s> 48 bytes

```r
function(L)c(rev(o<-L[order(nchar(L))]),o)[!0:1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYw9C8IwFAD3/IqaKYEWdJW6OkhVcK0dnvkwQfpeeYnm58fqdMNxx9U3fddU/0aTI6EatFHsPor6bhiJrWOFJgCvQk@6JT1utvvdVA1k5VUygKqVUus2ueUg7yi1eFARwEwliRQcR@@v/kI5R3wGmMVr5S3@nlbMEO0ZOAKKhSMad6KA/6oQ2SOxS1nULw)

Sort by string lengths, then combine the reversed list with the sorted list, finally, take every 2nd element, starting at 1-based index 1.

Comment: `o<-L[...` The other way to 'arrow variables'.

A less important aside, `pryr::f(...)` works here for 46. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcw9C8IwEIDhPb@iZrqDFnQtdXWQquBaO5z5sEGaK5dg8dfHj@mdnleKr7qmKou8pW09GBD3Au6afmCxTiCaiQR6xBFrxmGzbXcjFkMZPCRDEWqtEevklr2@RY3qzqsiEV6TSpOT4P3FnznnEB8Tzer57TX8plbNFOyJJFBUi4Ro3JGn@Fcrsz2wuJRV@QA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @CriminallyVulgar using additional libraries turns this into a separate language, `R + pryr` which is why I typically avoid doing it unless there's a good reason to -- like for number theory questions, `numbers` is indispensable.

Answer (score 7):

## Javascript 77 bytes

Takes input as an array of strings, outputs an arrow-sorted array of strings.

```
s=>s.sort((a,b)=>a.length-b.length).reduce((m,x,i)=>i%2?[...m,x]:[x,...m],[])
```

### Explanation

```
s =>                                 // take input as an array of strings s
  s.sort((a,b)=>a.length-b.length)   // sort input by string length
  .reduce(                           // reduce
    (m,x,i)=>i%2?[...m,x]:[x,...m],  // if index is even, stick string x at the end of the memo
                                     // array, else at the beginning
    []                               // memo initialized to empty array
  )
```

Comment: I don't think you have to count `f=`. [77](https://tio.run/##Ncwxa8MwEIbh3b/CGEokUDR0CglOtg6FttDV9XCWJetSWxdOqp1/71qQbM97fNwVZoiG8Zb282F19Rrrc9SROAkBqpP1GfRow5D8vntAarb9n7FCTOqucJvgy@ul0Vpv3R6bu8psVdPKdQYuoazLpqg6WipVVMBMS8yK3jI69@U@KSUMg4cpn383fqPxwH3OCbD/AEYIuW6Mwdh38uH5YSHq34htTFXRngpDIdJo9UiDcAKkvhIGsfsJOylP6z8 "JavaScript (V8) – Try It Online")

Comment: That is inconsistent in the js code golf submissions from what I have seen. I'm happy to exclude it if it doesn't count.

Comment: I think it depends whether your function uses recursion. i.e. `f=x=>x?f(x-1)`. If so, you need to include `f` since you are calling it in your function. However, since you are not using recursion, you shouldn't have to include `f`. There are several posts in Meta, this one seems to explain it a little better. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9032/8340

Comment: That would explain the inconsistencies I've seen.

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 51 bytes

```ruby
->l{r=1;l.sort_by!(&:size).map{l[r-=2]||(l*2)[~r]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3NDoIwEITvPgX2YEB@Ejlq8OjBRE28ksa00EojULItIQj46rUkauLl25ndnV1oaW94YsJ9OUCy2ZWRkqBvtF@6q60ST@ZFFWmGMoUwifE4uuU69tIX4GkyTauVw9MUqYKB4PzCz1JrUd8LUqEAPay6iqwgkFtXEZGfCAhSW0NlZ0kAZKesaEDUGTvKYp7Nxzop84MEpjTCePH7Q@Yotciyv76PAgf5H36Lb1fMGw)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
LÞŒœm"-Ẏ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n8Lyjk45OzlXSfbir7//D3VsOt0f@/5@UX86VWFSUX17MVZyRWpSZluaf5pdfUpKZl56RmMuVDaSDMpMzEotSuHITM1N8E4syE/O4Cooy85JTvfIz8sC6yvPzU9zyi1KLSwA)

```
LÞŒœṚ;¥/
```

is also 8 bytes.

Thanks to @EriktheOutgolfer and @JonathanAllan for both offering golfs to save a byte.

Comment: Nice! Clever golf: `Ṛ€1¦` can become `m"-`.

Comment: Or you could go for `LÞŒœṚ;¥/`

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 89 bytes

```cs
n=>(n=n.OrderBy(x=>x.Length)).Where((a,b)=>b%2>0).Reverse().Concat(n.Where((a,b)=>b%2<1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BSwMxFITv@zMCQh6soXrtJoeKBYta6KUH9ZDNvjSh7ou8pG5F/O3rLuJJbzPDzDcuX7ocx/WJXHN3S6ce2bav2OTCkQ6m/iczXo@kjSRNassd8upDnrU5q3ukQwkAah@QUUpbt6BNe3FtFqB2@I6cUYK6SeRskfSn1lwBjMtqz7Gg/DlTmxRJimcStZeEw9PLZyXaNIi6EpY5DXlWeQJF77f@MZUyrYLt5/g4yV10wXI3297G7sFytDS7twnvcJMC/RKGlLp1YsxFVF8AsKzGbw)

Answer (score 5):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 24 bytes

**Solution:**

```
x(<#:'x)(|&~w),&w:2!!#x:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v0LDRtlKvUJTo0atrlxTR63cykhRUbnCSkMpKb9cyVopsagov7wYyCjOSC3KTEvzT/PLLynJzEvPSMwFimYDWUGZyRmJRSlAXm5iZopvYlFmYh6QU1CUmZec6pWfkQfVXZ6fn@KWX5RaXKKk@f8/jS0AAA)

**Explanation:**

Generate the `6 4 2 0 1 3 5` sequence, use that to index into the ascending lengths of input, and use that to index into the original array:

```
x(<#:'x)(|&~w),&w:2!!#x: / the solution
                      x: / save input as x
                     #   / count (#) of x
                    !    / range 0 to ...
                  2!     / modulo 2
                w:       / save as w
               &         / indices where true
              ,          / join with
        (    )           / do this together
           ~w            / not (~) w
          &              / indices where true
         |               / reverse
 (     )                 / do this together
   #:'x                  / count (#:) of each (') x
  <                      / indices to sort ascending
x                        / index into x
```

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 11 bytes

```
,~`,/@\:#&>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYu9CsIwFEb3PsWHgkWIUddqiyB0EH@gs6CxTUyU5spNIZuvHovD4SznvNJE5gZlgRwCKxQjC4l9c6yT@N7FcnctprMqzbNQSmw38rYeywdFKGaKAcFqdsZczJmGwfmnVT3eoxvXWsUdeuW6k2KnPD7sfKsPZP3/ikRdTazDkGeZbi2hgkFIPw)

We sort it down first.

Then we reduce the list form right to left, but alternating which side we put the new element on.  Done.

Comment: Very nice! You have a space at the end though, remove it for 11 bytes :)

Comment: Thanks Galen.  Fixed!

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Kevin Cruijssen*

I/O is a list of strings.
Link is modified for newline separated I/O for easier testing.

```
éι`Rì
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcu7CYAwEADQ/gazEFRwAs98zCHm5BJI40KCC4id6V0pitWrHgccyZSt5P05hz4f5b7KyAlQhFOA4IyQtZ1tOUbyk8MF5s@elEPRsCDpBoXQwyrklanZ@X8lZl2xmBBf)

**Explanation**

```
é       # sort by length ascending
 ι      # uninterleave into 2 parts, both sorted ascending
   `    # push the 2 parts separately to the stack
    R   # reverse the second part
     ì  # and append it to the first
```

Comment: You can remove the first `R` and replace `«` with `i` to save a byte, since the third bullet-point rule allows both versions of uninterleaving.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Oh yeah, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>144</del> 141 bytes

```php
function($a){usort($a,function($b,$c){return strlen($b)-strlen($c);});$e=[];foreach($a as$d)(array_.[unshift,push][++$i%2])($e,$d);return$e;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBBTwMhEIXP7q/ggNklRWO8YuNJY4zaxutm07DsIMQWyMDamKa/fQXbTS/wvcfkzQzBhOnhMZhAANHjBiF4TNZ9NXdMEKqXkx6dSta7hkp2GGN@zcQvbs@pYgeENKIjMeEWisluZlRMHJmgsGw7oT2CVCYHEBnpwBqJKH83t@3oorE68TBG07WLBbXX9x1rKPBcJU7hFMRxEhVNEFMkS9JWhLR17/c1J3UO8vtYKBpAq/VKf/hUFjFyV@zvjJ9WGYlDkTtph3eJVrqiAlqn4NUbNyfsvR@e87Qx1R3/byRrXvd9PpSaLe8ga@1HzFeEH3BF5j0gU67pRFXNK5Pz3DJmIowcqitQxhO7C1s/QEPWL@vN0@qN509vTiWMX8wziOo4/QE)

-3 bytes thanks to [@Ismael Miguel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/14732/ismael-miguel)!

Comment: nice one. Where can I read more about `[array_unshift,array_push][++$i%2]($e,$d)`?

Comment: @abhig10 sure. It's an array with the two function names `['array_push','array_unshift']` with `[++$i%2]` as the index of the array alternating between a `0` or `1` so will evaluate to the other function each time. PHP's "variable functions" let you assign a varible to a function and execute by calling with parenthesis (ex: `$f='array_push'; $f($e,$d);` == `array_push($e,$d)`) so the `($e,$d)` is then calling the evaluated element of the array. Just a shorter way to do `if (++$i%2) array_push($e,$d); else array_unshift($e,$e);`. Guess there was some PHP syntactic sugar after all!

Comment: Okay, it took me sometime to understand this. Awesome.

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by replacing `[array_unshift,array_push][++$i%2]($e,$d)` with `(array_.[unshift,push][++$i%2])($e,$d)`. What I did was to remove the repeated `array_`, concatenated it and then the result is passed to the call.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel that's brilliant.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 66 bytes

```powershell
1..($a=$args|sort l*).count|?{$_%2}|%{$a[-$_];$x=,$a[-++$_]+$x};$x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYhLCoMwEECv0sVItNFA3Yr0ICISZNRCyEgSq2A8@xhX77PSjs4vaAzzR6kcdAvazT56cuFl3oUaabMhfk8YsvqK2Qm6q2DoGzja8nEpU0k4rnSYWZBFwWKizT34TQHRJvP4T7wB)

Takes input via splatting, which manifests on TIO as separate command-line arguments. `sort`s on the `l`ength, stores that into `$a`, and constructs a range from `1` up to the `count` of input strings. We then pull out only the odd ones `?{$_%2}` and feed those into a loop `|%{...}`. Each iteration, we put the "last", then the "third from last", and so on onto the pipeline with `$a[-$_]`. Separately, we also accumulate into `$x` the "second from last", "fourth from last", etc. Out of the loop and the pipeline is flushed (so those elements are output) and then we output `$x`. In both instances, the default output gives us newlines between items automatically.

Answer (score 4):

## MATLAB, 87 bytes

```
function f(y);[B,I]=sort(cellfun(@(x)length(x),y));{y{flip(I(1:2:end))},y{I(2:2:end)}}'
```

Takes input as cell array of strings, outputs column of strings (not sure if that's legal)

```
> s = {'qweq qwe qw','qweqw','12132132131231231','asdasdasda','qwe','w'};
> f(s)
> >> 
> ans =
> 
>   6×1 cell array
> 
>     {'qweq qwe qw'      }
>     {'qweqw'            }
>     {'qwe'              }
>     {'1234'             }
>     {'asdasdasda'       }
>     {'12132132131231231'}
```

PS: Thanks  Sanchises for pointing to a bug with odd-length inputs

Comment: This fails on odd number of input strings, e.g. `f({'loooooooong','medium','short'})`

Comment: Also some general golfing tips: the `end` is optional for a `function`. Using `function x=f(y);x={...}'` is shorter than `function f(y);disp({...}')`.

Comment: If you're stuck, [here's how I would do it.](https://tio.run/##PU@xbsIwEN35ilsq21KElHQjilR1y1IWNsRwOGdiybEDdpqGim9Pj1Cwnp/fu3e6k4NO@E3zbAavkw0erpWRkyr3n1l9qGK4JKnJOY7lh/xRjvwptSyySanyWu2Ns72cZC2LTbEh3yjFEdv8aQ@inFnAG3yFBKG/L0EHvGlXb@FIGodIMBJo9CJB71ATpJZ9aAisB4RIPV4wEaw7MNbRerUy8lecRzoDE1@RLe7@5kX@/kBeLOAaxuYfj0bmUdzUMsWF1/EnDjpq7NCxiC1/nrvmPw "Octave – Try It Online")

Comment: @Sanchises thanks for pointing bug out. I did fix it exactly like you did. My issue with `disp` is i am not sure what output rules are. Should it be pure text or not? or `disp({...})` is okay or even just `x={...}` as you suggest

Comment: That question can be quite tricky to answer. In general however, input/output is as flexible as possible so you can focus on the main challenge (there's a list of allowed I/O by default on meta) and in this case, no extra restrictions are specified by the OP. In my experience, just `y=input('');doSomething()` (without trailing semicolon to output the result) is shortest in MATLAB

Comment: (and one final hint: note that my solution was actually three bytes shorter still; it's really worth looking at what all the different braces actually do wrt cell arrays)

Comment: @Sanchises my MATLAB doesn't allow removing `end` from function definition :-(

Comment: Interesting, what version do you use?

Comment: @Sanchises oh my bad. You cannot omit  `end` in in-script define functions. But saving function in a file allows it!

Comment: what version of MATLAB is this? I'm trying to golf this down but can't get it to work on my local version (R2016a)

Comment: This can be [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330GjUjM6LSezQKPCtlIjuk7HM9a2OL@oRCM5NScnrTRPwyEnNS@9JEOnUhMIdCpiNQytjKxS81I0/6dpVKsXlqcWKgAJIFbXAfNAtKGRoTEEGRqBEVAssTgFiiAKgWS5eq3mfwA) in Octave.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
{⍵[⍋-@(2∘|)⍋⍋≢¨⍵]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR79boR73dug4aRo86ZtRoAtkg1Lno0AqgVGzt/7RHbRMe9fY96pvq6f@oq/nQeuNHbROBvOAgZyAZ4uEZ/B8okKYANsn@Ue8KoF6wTp1DK3RigEoSAQ)

Fixed the bug  thanks to @ngn.

Explanation:

```apl
{⍵[⍋-@(2∘|)⍋⍋≢¨⍵]}
{                } ⍝ Function. Takes a single argument: ⍵, list of strings
             ≢¨⍵   ⍝ The length of each element in the list
           ⍋⍋      ⍝ Sort the lengths
    -@(2∘|)        ⍝ At (@) elements divisible by 2 (|), negate (-)
                   ⍝     gives -1 2 -3 4 -5
   ⍋               ⍝ Sort this list again, gives the indices of that list ^ sorted
 ⍵[             ]  ⍝ Use these indices to index into the argument
```

---

[¹](https://github.com/vendethiel/trying.apl/blob/master/ex/arrow-strings.dyalog)

Comment: `≢¨×¯1*⍳∘⍴` -> `(⊢∘-\≢¨)` and it gets even shorter if you turn it into a dfn

Comment: however, i'm not sure this algorithm is correct. we should negate the length of every other string in their sorted order, not in the order they come from the input

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, <s>31</s> 38 bytes

See Adams comment

```
⊃n[(⍳⍴n)~a],⌽n[a←2×⍳⌊.5×⍴n←n[⍒∊⍴¨n←⎕]]
```

[Try it online Courtesy of Dyalog Classic!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/4/6mrOi9Z41Lv5Ue@WPM26xFidRz1786ITgSqMDk8Hifd06ZmCWFvygGJ50Y96Jz3q6AJyD60ACQCNi439DzTqfxqXuqGRugKQMDbBR5mamVsQZgIA)

Prompts for a nested vector of strings

Comment: Does APL+ not have Monadic `≢` "tally" to replace `∊⍴` ?

Comment: Fails on [`'12' '1234' '1234' '1234' '1234' '12345678' '12345678' '12345678' '12345678'`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/4/6mrWSHzUNjFPU@dRz14Qc8Kjni4908PTH/VuydN81DY5DyiUF/2od9Kjji6g2KEVIAGgKbH/gQb8T@NSNzRSVwASxib4KFMzcwvCTAA "APL (Dyalog Classic) – Try It Online"). Clearly, the result should have been `'12345678' '12345678' '1234' '1234' '12' '1234' '1234' '12345678' '12345678'`

Comment: @Adám My ancient version of APL+ does not have ≢. Agreed on your second comment I will take a look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 26 bytes

```
N$`
$.&
*\,2,^A`.+
,2,G`.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctBCoMwEEDR/ZwjuKgi2Bt0Y0FQwbWIU5M0g5iRSSDHT0NX72@@mEgeu5wntYNqK3iszbPZXntbQ4l3MecPJ0ARTgGCM0LWznbiWM6vwwvO4kKHQ9FwIekRhdDDLeQPM7Dz/ysx657FhPgD) Explanation:

```
N$`
$.&
```

Sort the lines in ascending order of length (`$.&` returns the length of the line).

```
*\,2,^A`.+
```

Temporarily delete alternate lines and output the remaining lines in reverse order.

```
,2,G`.+
```

Keep the only lines that were temporarily deleted and output them.

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 8 bytes

```
ñÊó g0_w
```

-3 bytes thanks to Shaggy!

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8crzIGcwX3c=&input=WyJib3ciLAoiYXJyb3dzIiwKInNoZXJpZmZPZk5vdHRpbmdoYW0iLAoia2luZ1JpY2hhcmQiLAoibWFpZE1hcmlhbiIsCiJwcmluY2VKb2huIiwKInNoZXJ3b29kRm9yZXN0Il0KLVE)

Comment: [10 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8cr8z3XDZzBfdw==&input=WyJib3ciLAoiYXJyb3dzIiwKInNoZXJpZmZPZk5vdHRpbmdoYW0iLAoia2luZ1JpY2hhcmQiLAoibWFpZE1hcmlhbiIsCiJwcmluY2VKb2huIiwKInNoZXJ3b29kRm9yZXN0Il0KLVE=) with output as a 2D-array, which would seem to be allowed.

Comment: Or, maybe, [8 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8crzIGcwX3c=&input=WyJib3ciLAoiYXJyb3dzIiwKInNoZXJpZmZPZk5vdHRpbmdoYW0iLAoia2luZ1JpY2hhcmQiLAoibWFpZE1hcmlhbiIsCiJwcmluY2VKb2huIiwKInNoZXJ3b29kRm9yZXN0Il0KLVE=)? On my phone so haven't tested it properly.

Comment: @Shaggy I was looking for a function to find every nth element, but I couldn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: there's also `A.ë()` but I don't know if that'll lead to a shorter solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 10 bytes

```
el∫v:v+2%ụ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/PzXnUcfqMqsybSPVh7uX/v8f/ahhTlJ@@aOGuQpAVmJRUX55MZRTnJFalJmW5p/ml19SkpmXnpGYC5XJBvKCMpMzEotSoCK5iZkpvolFmYl5UIGCosy85FSv/Iw8JNPK8/NT3PKLUotLgIKxAA)

```
e		| eval as Gaia code (list of strings)
 l∫		| ∫ort by lengths (ascending)
   v:v		| reverse, dup, reverse
      +		| concatenate lists
       2%	| take every other element
         ụ	| join by newlines and output
```

Comment: i like that your comments in unwrapped code form an arrow of strings

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 49 bytes

```powershell
$args|sort l*|sort{$_.Length*($global:x=-$x*2+1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3NCsJADITvfYoeFlcrCnoUvHoQf8AXkLTNdhe3G8muVlCfvcYf8JLMTPgmZ@qQo0Xve2XyZX7vFXATH5E45b747Ls6TjcYmmSLoWo8leAXt@VE3Yr5eDZ69s8sGwisS@p0roGZuihCWtkZszc7SsmFxkIr6UnUwVUWuBbXgqu3wA6CmDO7UOGabPjRHVG9IsaYdKb19wnIrSxlVNU/pICSGLrwm8QrvhuMMwlF9S8)

The double [distillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distillation).

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 84 bytes

Input is a table variable

```sql
SELECT a FROM(SELECT*,row_number()over(order by len(a))r
FROM @)x order by(r%2-.5)*r
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1023281/arrow-those-variables)**

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 31 bytes

```perl6
*.sort(&chars).sort:{$++%2*$--}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY09C8JAEET7/IpFoiTGWFhY@JHSQlDBWpBLsuedml3ZOw1B/O2nsXozxZt5oNznoelgpGEdxlPH4pNRZZS49F8W7zjLhrNxnOefsIyc6kAn8TmdXtlSMjjRIJ1AD9As0arkFpQItw6cQbFaH/Sevbd0MaqB249H28/X0Chb75RYRfAQSxVu2dDfapnrDQs6X0yilYKyhKrqIxP@bp4CDl9IoK32iFSELw)

Sort by string length, then by static sequence 0, -1, 0, -3, 0, -5, ...

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript  95 Bytes

```
s=>s.sort((x,y)=>x.length-y.length).reduce((a,e,i)=>{i%2?a.push(e):a.unshift(e);return a;},[]);
```

Comment: -1 `s.sort()` sorts the strings lexicographically, not by string length.

Comment: Right, (x,y)=>x.length-y.length, should fix that.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>136</s> 128 bytes

```c
S(a,b)int**a,**b;{a=strlen(*b)-strlen(*a);}f(l,s,o,i,b,e)int**s,**o;{qsort(s,l,8,S);e=l-1;for(i=b=0;i-l;)o[i++%2?b++:e--]=s[i];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY89b8MgEIb3/goUKRIfh5R0qkpQ50rd0s31AMh2kCikQDLU8m@nENe38KKH5@4wfDKmlDNWoIn1mVIFlGoxK5lydIPHVBO@RUXEMmIHCQJY0DCsSqpKEPNPCjHjBA5e4EzEIB0/ijFEbKWWB2G5EyR0lrH985tm7HXgvJeps71YSu2DvpX1uAUVJwPIXFREtOZ71xM0P6FajVrxiCum4Zavt4xktZ0LBif7O4QRN0oJxa0VPxKyOuP/HdqIO6vnqm84RFSXPQhkT@tDgRiz5AFbXWNdYMS7ffryu02uH6j@UspH8NMQCy@fF@XLe/4D)

-8 bytes thanks to ceilingcat.

The function `f` is the solution. It takes the number of strings, the strings themselves, and the output buffer as arguments (plus four more used internally).

Comment: Why is `./.bin.tio` in the [output](https://tio.run/##NY9BTwMhEIXv/grSpAmwbFI9GXHjzYOJmthj7YFloTuRMhWoTWz62xF27Vx4yZvvzUO3O61zXlMleqZHFThXgvNenlUXU3DGU96z9ioVkxdLnYgCRRIgemH@qVgoFDzJ83fEkGgUTtyLNZOmc@2ttBgodH23ktA62TTAcAPLu6e@aR5M2267uIGtvGTwiewVeFqFCjstSM0nvOifzZaR8w0pU12Qk5xtjsd0OCbSFdo51DTCr0FLp3Ks0prN@5bOsTVQkBm7WhhIabmSBB7rkiS16GTVOYRy1tLFMn76xRUttQt9ybnHU1Yh4CnmOJoA1r7bN0wJ/G5U@/xV3g@odYZcPji8qgDK55qpzQuOfqJOiMMzBhPTHw)?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Probably because their footer is using all of `argv`, which includes the filename

Comment: Exactly, it was just a quick test. One can construct any data that takes appropriate format. I'll update the TIO link later.

Comment: haha, the problem with these short variable names: you forget what you hat `t` for in the first place and keep it around even when you don't need it!

Comment: [122 bytes](https://tio.run/##NZDNTgMhFEb3PgVp0oSfS1JdGZG4NnFXd2MXQJgpCUIF2oWTeXaEjnM3fORwLhcMn4yp9YgVaOJjmKgCqsWsZC7J24CpJnyLiohlxB4yRHCgwa5GBhrF/JNjKjiDlR6e4UjEGBN2UsuDcNwLEgfH2P7pTTP2wrk9yTy4k1iqCwV9KxdwDypNBpA5q4Roy7fhRND8gFp16sQ9rpjGa7lcC5LN9j4anN2vjSPulBKKeyv@SMjqjP976FfcWFtXfcMxoTbsQSD3uh4UiDFH7rDXJbUBRrzb56@w2@T2gOYvtX60b7Cp8vp5VqG@lz8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>116</s> 101 bytes

```
func[b][sort/compare b func[x y][(length? x)> length? y]collect[forall b[keep take b]keep reverse b]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY09TwMxDIb3/gorU5nYGcrGgARIXaMMTuI00d3FJ1/Ktb/@6hSQYGNJntd6P4TidqRo3S49belcg/XOLiztMfA0oxB4uJ8vcHV2P1I9tfwMl4cD/PDVBR5HCs0mFhxH8HYgmqHhoGl3Z6FPkqVLt6mLMGRYIYE1aMB4r08IxoGdpdQGq4MvMGb3186V1Jv4LPot2lq7LKmR0j/ynlcNoAivS2/IJCWlj/TOrZV6yjjpdVA6lpBRoqoJS3xDKdinem2gV871O70yxxedWNrv@e0G)

Answer (score 1):

## perl 5 (`-p0777F/\n/ -M5.01`), 59 bytes

```
for$x(sort{$b=~y///c-length$a}@F){--$|?$\="$x
".$\:say$x}}{
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##HcvBCoIwGADg@x5DdqjDmh1ECKROHgILOnuZurmR7h//Bipmj96KTt/pcxKHLEYFSOedBwwrbYr3wjlv2SBtHzQV26Xcr4zR15nWRUJnkhxoffJiofO2rTE2MBGBCJMnXks0St3VDUIwttdiJM@fD9NqgR0ZhekqgUZY4tDYVl5B2/@aALoSUPpAPuCCAesjc2me5yWvLY@syg7p8Qs)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
m!ÖL¹Ċ2§+ṡŀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/qKnx0Lb/uYqHp/kc2nmky@jQcu2HOxcebfj//39SfjlXYlFRfnkxV3FGalFmWpp/ml9@SUlmXnpGYi5XNpAOykzOSCxK4cpNzEzxTSzKTMzjKijKzEtO9crPyAPrKs/PT3HLL0otLgEA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `a`, 7 bytes

```
µL;yṘ$"
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=a&code=%C2%B5L%3By%E1%B9%98%24%22&inputs=abcd%0Aabc%0Aab%0Aa&header=&footer=f%E2%81%8B)

Outputs as a list of two lists of lines.

The header and footer allow for multiline IO.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

Input as an array of lines, output as an array of 2 arrays of lines, one for each half of the list.

```
ñÊó vw
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=tw&code=8crzIHZ3&footer=VmO3tw&input=Im9uZQpmb3VyCnNldmVuCmZpZnRlZW4i) (Header & footer allow for I/O as newline separated string)

```
ñÊó vw     :Implicit input of array
ñ          :Sort by
 Ê         :  Length
  ó        :Uninterleave
    v      :Modify first element
     w     :  Reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 41 bytes

```julia
!s=sort(s,by=length)[∪(end:-2:1,1:end)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYwxbsMwDEV33iKaJCAd3NGB1w4FmgBd2w60RUVsHDKQlLpZMvcsOVYv4srp9D4@@d/neWRsvud5lbusqdi87i/dSLIv0b39/twsiW8fHttm3bQ1uo/5mjvrOZ9GvNhVBdeRc5tTYimjWPMuxjmAqzEGep0AU9IpQ46UOIRd2GopLPuIRzhUvvIQMXk4IvsXTIwCi2qgZ41yX02q/kkT5QKL8y5WIQh6TpDpiwQCh0KVy@n/AaHvYRiWZv4D)

- input and output are vectors of strings
- `end:-2:1` takes every second index, starting from the end
- `1:end` is all indices
- `∪` (=`union`) removes duplicates